# Creating a three states checkbox on android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm stuck in front of a big problem:
I'd like to make three state checkbox on android.
It's a checkbox upon a ListView with checkboxes. It should allows user to switch between three states:

- all checked
- none checked
- misc checked

And optionally retain the misc state on change.

If I'm right I should make a subclass of the CompoundButton class and implement a int mstate intead of the boolean mchecked.
Then I should override the event listener, the functions to save the state, and the state getter and setter.

My question is basically how can I implement that ?
How to switch between the drawable states ? (I have implemented the middle_state in the xml) and how to correctly implement the event handler?

Here is the implementation I started:

```
public class TriStateCheckBox extends CompoundButton{
    private int state;

    public TriStateCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public static interface onCheckChangedListener{
        void onCheckChanged(TriStateCheckBox view, int state);
    }

    public void onCheckChanged(TriStateCheckBox view, int state){
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the stock CompoundButton:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.widget;

import com.android.internal.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewDebug;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;

/**
 * <p>
 * A button with two states, checked and unchecked. When the button is pressed
 * or clicked, the state changes automatically.
 * </p>
 *
 * <p><strong>XML attributes</strong></p>
 * <p>
 * See {@link android.R.styleable#CompoundButton
 * CompoundButton Attributes}, {@link android.R.styleable#Button Button
 * Attributes}, {@link android.R.styleable#TextView TextView Attributes}, {@link
 * android.R.styleable#View View Attributes}
 * </p>
 */
public abstract class CompoundButton extends Button implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;
    private int mButtonResource;
    private boolean mBroadcasting;
    private Drawable mButtonDrawable;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener;

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        R.attr.state_checked
    };

    public CompoundButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CompoundButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CompoundButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.CompoundButton, defStyle, 0);

        Drawable d = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.CompoundButton_button);
        if (d != null) {
            setButtonDrawable(d);
        }

        boolean checked = a
                .getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.CompoundButton_checked, false);
        setChecked(checked);

        a.recycle();
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        /*
         * XXX: These are tiny, need some surrounding 'expanded touch area',
         * which will need to be implemented in Button if we only override
         * performClick()
         */

        /* When clicked, toggle the state */
        toggle();
        return super.performClick();
    }

    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Changes the checked state of this button.</p>
     *
     * @param checked true to check the button, false to uncheck it
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();

            // Avoid infinite recursions if setChecked() is called from a listener
            if (mBroadcasting) {
                return;
            }

            mBroadcasting = true;
            if (mOnCheckedChangeListener != null) {
                mOnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
            }
            if (mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener != null) {
                mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
            }

            mBroadcasting = false;            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the checked state of this button
     * changes.
     *
     * @param listener the callback to call on checked state change
     */
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        mOnCheckedChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the checked state of this button
     * changes. This callback is used for internal purpose only.
     *
     * @param listener the callback to call on checked state change
     * @hide
     */
    void setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        mOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked state
     * of a compound button changed.
     */
    public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        /**
         * Called when the checked state of a compound button has changed.
         *
         * @param buttonView The compound button view whose state has changed.
         * @param isChecked  The new checked state of buttonView.
         */
        void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked);
    }

    /**
     * Set the background to a given Drawable, identified by its resource id.
     *
     * @param resid the resource id of the drawable to use as the background 
     */
    public void setButtonDrawable(int resid) {
        if (resid != 0 && resid == mButtonResource) {
            return;
        }

        mButtonResource = resid;

        Drawable d = null;
        if (mButtonResource != 0) {
            d = getResources().getDrawable(mButtonResource);
        }
        setButtonDrawable(d);
    }

    /**
     * Set the background to a given Drawable
     *
     * @param d The Drawable to use as the background
     */
    public void setButtonDrawable(Drawable d) {
        if (d != null) {
            if (mButtonDrawable != null) {
                mButtonDrawable.setCallback(null);
                unscheduleDrawable(mButtonDrawable);
            }
            d.setCallback(this);
            d.setState(getDrawableState());
            d.setVisible(getVisibility() == VISIBLE, false);
            mButtonDrawable = d;
            mButtonDrawable.setState(null);
            setMinHeight(mButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        }

        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setChecked(mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setCheckable(true);
        info.setChecked(mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final Drawable buttonDrawable = mButtonDrawable;
        if (buttonDrawable != null) {
            final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
            final int height = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            int y = 0;

            switch (verticalGravity) {
                case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                    y = getHeight() - height;
                    break;
                case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                    y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                    break;
            }

            buttonDrawable.setBounds(0, y, buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), y + height);
            buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();

        if (mButtonDrawable != null) {
            int[] myDrawableState = getDrawableState();

            // Set the state of the Drawable
            mButtonDrawable.setState(myDrawableState);

            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
        return super.verifyDrawable(who) || who == mButtonDrawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() {
        super.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
        if (mButtonDrawable != null) mButtonDrawable.jumpToCurrentState();
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        boolean checked;

        /**
         * Constructor called from {@link CompoundButton#onSaveInstanceState()}
         */
        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        /**
         * Constructor called from {@link #CREATOR}
         */
        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            checked = (Boolean)in.readValue(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeValue(checked);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CompoundButton.SavedState{"
                    + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
                    + " checked=" + checked + "}";
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        // Force our ancestor class to save its state
        setFreezesText(true);
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);

        ss.checked = isChecked();
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setChecked(ss.checked);
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Here is my xml state-liste implementation (working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed" /> <!-- unchecked pressed -->

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_selected" /> <!-- unchecked selected -->

    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:state_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" /> <!-- checked -->

    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_pressed" /> <!-- checked pressed-->

    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_selected" /> <!-- checked selected-->

    <item android:state_middle="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:state_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_middle" /> <!-- middle -->        

    <item android:state_middle="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_middle_pressed" /> <!-- middle pressed-->

    <item android:state_middle="true"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_middle_selected"  /> <!-- middle selected--> 

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" /> <!-- unchecked -->
</selector>
```

And here is the stock xml implementation for the checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Enabled states -->

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />


    <!-- Disabled states -->

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_disable" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_disable" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_disable_focused" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_disable_focused" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_disable" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_disable" />

</selector>
```

Comment: For implementing the visual aspect, use the [`level-list` drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList).

Comment: i already made a custom drawable as a state-liste and it works well with the stock checkbox code. But why the level-list drawable when the original checkbox uses state-liste ?

Comment: @Thomas  Did you found any suitable methodology ?

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 This is a very old topic, I'm not sure anymore...
Have a look by yourself: https://github.com/feeeermendoza/dev.android.HFUNotenalarm

Answer (score 23):

Old topic, but I give my solution for who  are interessed:

```
public class CheckBoxTriStates extends CheckBox {
    static private final int UNKNOW = -1;
    static private final int UNCHECKED = 0;
    static private final int CHECKED = 1;
    private int state;

    public CheckBoxTriStates(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CheckBoxTriStates(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CheckBoxTriStates(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        state = UNKNOW;
        updateBtn();

        setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                switch (state) {
                    default:
                    case UNKNOW:
                        state = UNCHECKED;
                        break;
                    case UNCHECKED:
                        state = CHECKED;
                        break;
                    case CHECKED:
                        state = UNKNOW;
                        break;
                }
                updateBtn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateBtn() {
        int btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_indeterminate_black;
        switch (state) {
            default:
            case UNKNOW:
                btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_indeterminate_black;
                break;
            case UNCHECKED:
                btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_unchecked_black;
                break;
            case CHECKED:
                btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_checked_black;
                break;
        }

        setButtonDrawable(btnDrawable);
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
        updateBtn();
    }
}
```

You can find the button resources [Here](https://material.io/icons/). It work perfect.

Comment: please review my [updated version](https://gist.github.com/kevin-barrientos/d75a5baa13a686367d45d17aaec7f030) of your implementation that adds support for a client to set up his own OnCheckedChangeListener and to restore the correct state when needed.

Comment: @ingkevin You have an error in your updated version: if you use in.readInt() then you must write this value using out.writeInt() and not out.writeValue(). Or you'll break the unmarshalling process.

Answer (score 5):

Last version of material library supports three-states checkboxes.
Add this to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-rc01'
```

After that, you can set indeterminate state both in xml:

```
  <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedState="indeterminate" />
```

Or through code:

```
    checkbox.checkedState = when (childrenSelected) {
        0 -> MaterialCheckBox.STATE_UNCHECKED
        childrenTotal -> MaterialCheckBox.STATE_CHECKED
        else -> MaterialCheckBox.STATE_INDETERMINATE
    }
```

Where childrenSelected is the number of selected checkboxes. You can also customize checkbox appearance as you like, see full documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/checkbox/MaterialCheckBox

Comment: In xml layout use com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox.

Answer (score 1):

If you want checkbox without Vector Animation while changing state then try this simple custom class for checkbox with indeterminate state

check [github](https://github.com/imhardiklakhani/IndeterminateCheckbox) example here

Answer (score 1):

previously I wanted to do the same thing. after doing some hard research I approached this.

**pros:**

- animated button
- material design

---

TriStateMaterialCheckBox.kt:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.annotation.StyleableRes
import com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox

class TriStateMaterialCheckBox : MaterialCheckBox {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, com.google.android.material.R.attr.checkboxStyle)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        val sets = intArrayOf(R.attr.state)
        
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, sets)
        
        try {
            state = typedArray.getInt(ATTR_STATE, STATE_UNCHECKED)
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
        
        initComponent()
    }
    
    companion object {
        // @formatter:off
        @StyleableRes private const val ATTR_STATE = 0
        // @formatter:on
        
        const val STATE_UNCHECKED: Int = 0
        const val STATE_INDETERMINATE: Int = 1
        const val STATE_CHECKED: Int = 2
        
        private val UNCHECKED = intArrayOf(R.attr.state_unchecked)
        private val INDETERMINATE = intArrayOf(R.attr.state_indeterminate)
        private val CHECKED = intArrayOf(R.attr.state_checked)
    }
    
    private var isChangingState = false
    
    var state: Int
        @Throws(IllegalStateException::class)
        set(value) {
            if (isChangingState) return
            if (field == value) return
            isChangingState = true
            
            field = value
            isChecked = when (value) {
                STATE_UNCHECKED -> false
                STATE_INDETERMINATE -> true
                STATE_CHECKED -> true
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("$value is not a valid state for ${this.javaClass.name}")
            }
            refreshDrawableState()
            
            isChangingState = false
            
            onStateChanged?.let { it(this@TriStateMaterialCheckBox, value) }
        }
    
    var onStateChanged: ((TriStateMaterialCheckBox, Int) -> Unit)? = null
    
    private fun initComponent() {
        setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.tri_state_button)
        setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, _ ->
            state = when (state) {
                STATE_UNCHECKED -> STATE_CHECKED
                STATE_INDETERMINATE -> STATE_CHECKED
                STATE_CHECKED -> STATE_UNCHECKED
                else -> -1
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
        val drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1)
        
        mergeDrawableStates(
            drawableState, when (state) {
                STATE_UNCHECKED -> UNCHECKED
                STATE_INDETERMINATE -> INDETERMINATE
                STATE_CHECKED -> CHECKED
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("$state is not a valid state for ${this.javaClass.name}")
            }
        )
        
        return drawableState
    }
}
```

attrs.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="state" format="enum">
        <enum name="unchecked" value="0" />
        <enum name="indeterminate" value="1" />
        <enum name="checked" value="2" />
    </attr>
    
    <declare-styleable name="TriStateMaterialCheckBox">
        <attr name="state" />
        <attr name="state_unchecked" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_indeterminate" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_checked" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

tri_state_button.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unchecked" app:state_unchecked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_indeterminate" app:state_indeterminate="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked" app:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on using a CheckBox where each element have 3 states then the following might work but I haven't tried it:
- Make a class that extends the CheckBox class.
- Add a variable : "checkstate" of type int or byte. The class should have a Boolean "isChecked" variable. 
- Override the onClick or onCheck method so that it change the checkstate variable between the 3 states instead of toggling the isChecked variable. 
- Upon display, check the "checkstate" and do some visual effect to show the 3rd state.
- Finally, tell me if it works.