# 3 state switch button?

Tags: android, button, android-button

The requirement is to implement a 3 way switch button like this..

[image: switch]

[image: yes]

[insert switch with no-state]

Almost everywhere I checked, there were only 2-state Switch button and the only 3-way options I found were toggle.

Anyone have used/know how to tackle this situation?

Comment: Use a custom seekbar. Or, use two switches where one state of the A switch will enable the B switch.

Comment: @AlphaQ I'll try the seekbar idea out. Thanks.

Comment: Great question... SO marked as Too Broad? WTF?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

- You have to define a class that extends Checkbox
- define variables for check state
- Override the onClick or onCheck method to change that variable between the 3 states instead of toggling the isChecked variable.

```html
static private final int CHECKED = 1;
private int state;

public CheckBoxTriStates(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CheckBoxTriStates(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CheckBoxTriStates(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    state = UNKNOW;
    updateBtn();

    setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case UNKNOW:
                    state = UNCHECKED;
                    break;
                case UNCHECKED:
                    state = CHECKED;
                    break;
                case CHECKED:
                    state = UNKNOW;
                    break;
            }
            updateBtn();
        }
    });

}

private void updateBtn()
{
    int btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_indeterminate_black;
    switch (state)
    {
        case UNKNOW:
            btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_indeterminate_black;
            break;
        case UNCHECKED:
            btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_unchecked_black;
            break;
        case CHECKED:
            btnDrawable = R.drawable.ic_checkbox_checked_black;
            break;
    }
    setButtonDrawable(btnDrawable);

}
public int getState()
{
    return state;
}

public void setState(int state)
{
    this.state = state;
    updateBtn();
}

}
```

Comment: I had already found this answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939367/8090658
Thanks anyway