# Parent-Child Checkbox in Material Checkbox

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I have two cases that I want to implement:

```
[]Checkbox1
    []checkbox1.1
    []checkbox1.2
```

1. If I select parent node checkbox1 it should not select it's children.
2. If I select both the child, it should not select parent.

I am using mat checkboxes, any idea how it can be achieved.

Comment: Did you get answer to the above question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Material Component has this logic it self, at leats yet, look here, there is an issue reported:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/857

If you wanna extend the Material Check Button and add you the logic you can do it, have a look into this answer:
[Creating a three states checkbox on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511535/creating-a-three-states-checkbox-on-android)