# Firemonkey Checkbox : Is there a tristate option usable on Windows and MacOS platform?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am looking for a way to create a checkbox that has the status undefined as well as the status on and off. Is such a third state common on the Mac and if not, how do you solve it there understandably?

Comment: You might take a look at this Q&A:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511535/creating-a-three-states-checkbox-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a third state is supported natively by MacOS. Quote from [Apples Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/checkboxes):

> Use a mixed state when it makes sense. A checkbox should accurately
>   reflect its state. If a checkbox is used to globally enable and
>   disable multiple child checkboxes, it should show a mixed
>   state—reflected by a dash—when those children are not all in the same
>   state.

You will need to create your own button class to achieve this. Either using a FMX styled button that adds the tri-state option. Or a FMX wrapper around a native button. If you want to go native, you can use the [TMS mCL component suite](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsmcl.asp), which is not free though.